# Blurred map when I move in Folium

Tags: python, streamlit, folium

So I'm trying to display an interactive map using streamlit and folium but every time I move the map it becomes blurry.

I suppose it is a performance problem where things are getting processed over and over again but I can't seem to bypass it, even though I've tried using cache to only process things once but doesn't seem to change anything.

Am I doing something wrong ?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_folium import st_folium
import pandas as pd
import functools
from branca.colormap import LinearColormap

APP_TITLE = 'Agences du réseau'

done = False

def read_files():
    #df = pd.read_excel("data/data.xlsx")
    # For testing purpose use this generated dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Agence":["Ardèche", "Isère", "Savoie"], "Occupation":[3, 2, 1], "Commentaire": ["RAS", "RAS", "RAS"]})
    geo_data = gpd.read_file("data/departements.geojson")
    # Create a Folium map centered at the bounds
    m = folium.Map(location=[46.5, 2.5], zoom_start=6, tiles='CartoDB positron')

    # Create linear color scale from red to green
    color_scale = LinearColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00'],
                            vmin=df['Occupation'].min(), 
                            vmax=df['Occupation'].max())

    def style_function(feature):
        value = feature['properties']['Occupation']
        return {
            'fillColor': color_scale(value),
            'color': 'white',
            'weight': 1,
            'fillOpacity': 0.8
        }

    choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
        geo_data=geo_data,
        data=df,
        columns=["Agence", 'Occupation'],
        key_on='feature.properties.nom',
        line_opacity=0.8,
        highlight=False,
        fill_opacity=0.5,
        style_function=style_function  

    )


    choropleth.geojson.add_to(m)
    # Extract the boundaries of the GeoJSON data
    boundary_data = geo_data.boundary

    # Calculate the bounds of the boundary geometries
    bounds = boundary_data.total_bounds.tolist()


    # Add the boundaries to the map
    folium.GeoJson(boundary_data).add_to(m)



    return df, geo_data, m, choropleth

def display_map(geofile, df, geo_data, m, choropleth):

    
    # TEST
    df_indexed = df.set_index('Agence')
    global done
    if done == False:

        for feature in choropleth.geojson.data['features']:
            try:
                state_name = feature['properties']['nom']
                print(state_name)
                feature['properties']['Occupation'] = 'Population: ' + '{:,}'.format(df_indexed.loc[state_name, 'Occupation'][0]) if state_name in list(df_indexed.index) else ''
                feature['properties']['Commentaire'] = 'Reports/100K Population: ' + str(round(df_indexed.loc[state_name, 'Commentaire'][0])) if state_name in list(df_indexed.index) else ''
            except:
                pass
        done = True
    choropleth.geojson.add_child(
        folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(['nom', 'Occupation', 'Commentaire'], labels=False)
    )
    
    # Display the map in Streamlit
    st_map = st_folium(m, width=1200, height=800)
    print(st_map)
    state_name = ''
    if st_map['last_active_drawing']:
        state_name = st_map['last_active_drawing']['properties']['nom']
    return state_name

def main():
    df, geo_data, m, choropleth = read_files()
    st.set_page_config(APP_TITLE)
    st.title(APP_TITLE)
    display_map("data/departements.geojson", df, geo_data, m, choropleth)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The geojson file can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson, file "departements.geojson"

[image: Not blurred]

[image: Blurred]

Comment: I am not experienced with streamlit, but I would assume that the geojson file is cacheable as a stand-alone function. And adding the `returned_objects=[]` from the [manual](https://folium.streamlit.app/static_map) to the following code will eliminate the blurring. `st_map = st_folium(m, width=1200, height=800, returned_objects=[])`

Comment: seems like this is deprecated, I have the latest version and I get `unexpected keyword argument` error, inspect module confirms: `Signature (fig: branca.element.MacroElement, key: str = None, height: int = 700, width: int = 500)`

Comment: I used `branca:0.6.0` because I saw the word branca in the comments.